# Teamviewer cannot log in

Tags: teamviewer

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 64x. I can't login to team viewer. "The sign in request failed. The server did not respond. Please try again." This is the log file:

```
2013/03/04 14:33:50.457     8    19 G0   X ErrorHandler org 7de24d39, def 7dcd3960 cur 7d5f9f70
2013/03/04 14:33:50.464     8    19 G0   XTest extension: base 0, error 0, version 2.2
2013/03/04 14:33:50.465     8    19 G0   Wine: Wine DLL initialized
2013/03/04 14:33:50.465     8    19 G0   Wine: wine-1.5.19

2013/03/04 14:33:50.466     8    19 G0   Monitors: X11 Windowing System, \\.\DISPLAY1, 1920x1080 (0,0), flags=21
2013/03/04 14:33:50.466     8    19 G0   Monitors: X11 Windowing System, \\.\DISPLAY1, 1280x1024 (1920,56), flags=21
2013/03/04 14:33:50.468     8    19 G0   Opening local TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:5939
2013/03/04 14:33:50.468     8    19 G0   Local TCP connection established
2013/03/04 14:33:50.469     8    19 G0   Process ID:  L 20112 /  W 8
2013/03/04 14:33:50.579     8    19 G0   Received Control_InitIPC_Response processtype=1
2013/03/04 14:33:50.579     8    19 G0   Received Control_InitIPC_Response runningProcesses=3
2013/03/04 14:33:50.579     8    19 G0   InterProcess: Sending 3 queued control commands
2013/03/04 14:33:50.580     8    19 G0   Control_InitIPC_Response: all processes 3 completely initialized
2013/03/04 14:33:50.582     8    19 G0   ProxySearch: no PAC script detected via WPAD
2013/03/04 14:33:50.582     8     9 G0!! VerifySignature() : WinVerifyTrust failed, result=2, Errorcode=2
2013/03/04 14:33:50.583     8    19 G0   ProxySearch: no PAC script detected via WPAD
2013/03/04 14:33:50.583     8     9 G0!! MachineHooks: Library not found, Errorcode=2
2013/03/04 14:33:50.616     8     9 G0   X Error 8 on ???, Req 42.0 (#259 r65011719): BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
2013/03/04 14:33:50.721     8     9 G0!! DragDropRegistration: could not register window, HR=-2147221163
2013/03/04 14:33:50.744     8     9 G0!  BuddyWindow.Reconnect: user name or password empty on auto login
2013/03/04 14:33:50.746     8     9 G0   Tray created!
2013/03/04 14:33:50.749     8     9 G0   P_FORCE_WINSTATE_ONCE = WinState_Undefined
2013/03/04 14:33:50.754     8     9 G0   API: The API is not registered with Windows.
2013/03/04 14:34:00.754     8    21 G0   Timeout for master message.
2013/03/04 14:34:00.754     8    21 G0   Timeout for master message.
2013/03/04 14:34:00.754     8    21 G0   Timeout for master message.
2013/03/04 14:34:00.755     8    21 G0   Timeout for master message.
2013/03/04 14:34:18.706     8     9 G0!! BuddyList: SignIn failed. (SignIn Timeout), Errorcode=5
```

Comment: Which Login do you mean? The user Login or the remote Login via Teamviewer ID?
Do you use a Proxy? Is it defined in Teamviewer?

Comment: @patricks the user log in. I'd like to sign in to my Teamviewer account. I can do that on the web, but not on the desktop

Comment: @bizso09 - Are you using a proxy?  Have you verified the desktop client is using the proxy?

Comment: @Ramhound I've got a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.10 and I've got a wired internet connection. I don't think I'm running a proxy.